# Running test cases for C program in run time via python

Tags: python, c++, c, unit-testing, testing

I am working on a program in python wherein a .c file for a C program is opened, compiled and run. I have many test cases for the program which I need to check manually every time I run the program. Now there are about 15 to 16 C programs and they have about 100 test cases combined. So how should I write python program so that after running the C program using python, it will automatically load each test cases and direct its output to a specified file?

Comment: **Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service**. Please demonstrate what you have tried and how it is not working (c.f. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). You may want to [edit] your question to add more information.

Comment: You could use a shell script for that purpose, and you might generate that shell script (e.g. using `autogen`...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the following approach:

Step 1: Have the names of all the C programs and their corresponding Test cases stored in arrays in a python program.

Step 2: Iterate through the array of C programs and for each such iteration iterate through the array of Test cases for this C Program. In this inner iteration use the Popen utility to fire a test case for a C program. So for example C program is 'app' and test case is 'tc' use the following

```
tcProcess = subprocess.Popen( ['app','tc']) # assuming tc is going as an argument to app
```

Step 4: Now wait for the process to complete using wait() utility. Check the return code and proceed as per your requirement. If you don't choose to abort for failed process, then in the next iteration the program will pick up next test case and repeat the same process

```
return_code = tcProcess.wait ()
```

Instead of Popen you can also use call() method on subprocess and it automatically waits for the call to finish and wait() is not required.

Description of subprocess and its methods can be found here

```
 <https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was great one! I found out a way to do what I wanted using the redirection operators too like "filename" < testcases.txt > output.txt. Only the problem is that running this code for such a great amount of programs and testcases is a hectic.